# How to create a <select> element with polymer-dart repeat

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am trying to iterate a list to create a select drop-down box. My code is shown below as a web component

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<polymer-element name="epimss-name">
  <template>
    <label for='titleCmbo' id='titleLbl'>Title</label>

    <template repeat="{{title in titleList}}">
      <select id='titleCmbo'>
        <option value='{{title}}'>{{title}}</option>
      </select> 
    </template>

  </template>
  <script type="application/dart">

    import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

    @CustomTag( 'epimss-name' )
    class NameElement extends PolymerElement
    {
      final List<String> titleList = toObservable([ '', 'Dr', 'Miss', 'Mr', 'Mrs', 'Prof'  ]);
    }

  </script> </polymer-element>
</body>
</html>
```

As the code is, it creates a separate combo for each iteration.
If I move the  tags outside of the nested template, the editor complains.

What is the proper way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the template attribute on the option tag. It will repeat the option element and loop value for each item in the template collection.

```html
<select id="titleCmbo">
  <option value="{{title}}" template repeat="{{title in titleList}}">
    {{title}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: @st_clair_clarke You should accept the answer by clicking the check mark below the up/down-vote counter.